# Difference between two usages of TransformedDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am modeling the distribution of the sum of two dice throws as a `TransformedDistribution`

```
d1 = TransformedDistribution[x + y, {x, y}\[Distributed]DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}]]
```

and wanted to take random samples with

```
(* In[2] = *)
RandomVariate[d1]

(* Out[2] = RandomVariate[
       TransformedDistribution[\[FormalX]1 + \FormalX]2,
         {\[FormalX]1, \[FormalX]2} \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}]
       ]
     ]*)
```

but instead of a sample i get the unevaluated expression back. If i define my distribution like this

```
d2 = TransformedDistribution[x + y,
       {x \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}], 
        y \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}]}
     ]
```

instead, it works as expected:

```
(* In[3] = *)
RandomVariate[d2]

(* Out[3] = 7 *)
```

Can someone explain where this difference in behaviour comes from and if it's intended or should behave the same?

Comment: `d1` as you have defined does not evaluate as the distribution is univariate and you are asking it to be  bivariate, You could use `TransformedDistribution[
 x + y, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
  DiscreteUniformDistribution[{{1, 6}, {1, 6}}]]`

Comment: oh, i see, thanks for the explanation! If you put this as an answer i would accept it! Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you will beat the simplicity of:  `RandomInteger[{1, 6}] + RandomInteger[{1, 6}]` by using `RandomVariate[ TransformedBlah ]` ... especially if you need just one drawing at a time (rather than a million in advance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

d1 as defined does not evaluate as the distribution is univariate and you are asking it to be bivariate. You could use

```
TransformedDistribution[ x + y, {x, y} \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{{1, 6}, {1, 6}}]]
```